# that covers 30% of the whole tuition fees

Tags: relative-clauses

> I also got an annual merit scholarship from X University, **that** covers
>   30% of the tuition fees.

Is the use of "that" correct in the above? I think we have to use "which" for a non-defining adjective clause.
Could you please help me to clarify this?

Source: it was written by a teacher.

Comment: Source of quote please

Comment: You are right: you can't use "that" with supplementary (non-defining) relative clauses. Integrated (defining) relative clauses can have "that" or "which". Incidentally, please don't call relative clauses 'adjectival'; they're not -- they are modifiers. Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective, you know!

Comment: @BillJ But this is one of those supplementary *that* relative clauses discussed in H&P.

Comment: @Araucaria Surely not. Supplementary _that_ relatives are very rare, and this one doesn't fit the pattern of the ones that H&P give. I'd say that the comma is wrong and this is an integrated relative.

Comment: @BillJ The only reason it doesn't seem to fit the pattern, imo, is that it involves extraposition from noun phrase movement. Otherwise it's pretty much exactly the same. As for the comma, try replacing *that* with *which* and decide whether a comma is needed or not. I think you'll probably want to put one in.

Comment: @Araucaria I told the OP in the first place that a comma + "which" (but not "that") is fine. As a postposed integrated relative with "which" (or "that") it looks fine to me, but the OP specifically talks about 'non-defining', so I suppose we have to assume it's supplementary, and hence requires "which", since I can't see any way that it can be a supp _that_ relative -- why would it need to be?

Comment: @Araucaria Incidentally, if you read James K's answer, you'll see that he's got it all the wrong way round.  Integrated _which_ relative are common enough, and supplementary _that_ relatives are virtually unheard of.  I've only ever seen one or two, and in both cases they have a unique structure that is nothing at all like the OP's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its correct because there is no such rule.

"which" tends to be used in non-restrictive clauses, and "that" tends to be used in restrictive clauses.  But it is easy to find examples that don't follow this "rule". It is not uncommon to find non-restrictive clauses that use "that" and possible (but less common) to find restrictive clauses using which.

As a learner, you can choose "that" or "which" for restrictive and non-restrictive clauses and you won't be wrong. But be aware that native speakers won't always follow this.

In spoken language, the phrasing and intonation are more important than the choice of pronoun.

So the quoted sentence is correct, but could also be written with "which".

Comment: Note that, even though both are correct, *which* is more commonly used in the UK than in North America.

Comment: Also, I would question the use of the comma in the sentence. While also not wrong, it's stylistically awkward. If it's actually non-restrictive, I would drop **that** (or **which**) altogether and use a semicolon or a dash followed by **it**. Or make it two sentences.

Comment: I also got an annual merit scholarship from X University; it covers 30% of the tuition fees.